# Error while accessing value from a promise

Tags: javascript

I want to print individual properties of resolve and reject
in a paragraph according to the response with `id='details'` like User Id: id Name: user_name Status: status. But the problem is that when I enter correct ids like 89765, it doesn't get printed on the desired paragraph instead it shows up an error in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) {id: 89765, user_name: 'Aakash', status: 'authorized'}id: 89765status: "authorized"user_name: "Aakash"[[Prototype]]: Object
(anonymous) @ Assignment 3.html:54
authorization @ Assignment 3.html:38
authorization_check @ Assignment 3.html:27
```

and when I enter characters or 0 such error occurs((instead it should fire the reolve function and print it in the paragraph):

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid User ID
    at Assignment 3.html:41:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at authorization (Assignment 3.html:38:18)
    at HTMLButtonElement.authorization_check (Assignment 3.html:27:13)
(anonymous) @ Assignment 3.html:41
authorization @ Assignment 3.html:38
authorization_check @ Assignment 3.html:27
```

and if I enter any other id such as 89764 it shows this type of error(instead it should fire the reolve function and print it in the paragraph)

```
Uncaught (in promise) {id: 89764, user_name: undefined, status: 'authorized'}id: 89764status: "authorized"user_name: undefined[[Prototype]]: Object
(anonymous) @ Assignment 3.html:54
authorization @ Assignment 3.html:38
authorization_check @ Assignment 3.html:27
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Promise example</title>
</head>
<body>
    Enter User ID: <input type="text" id="id">
    <button id="btn">Submit</button>
    <br>
    <p id="details"></p>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        //document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = '';
      }

      var authorized_users = [89765,92014,51200];  
             var user_names = ['Aakash','Vikash','Anshuman'];

       document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',authorization_check);
       //document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',authorization);
       var id = 0;
       function authorization_check() {
            id = document.getElementById('id').value;  
            authorization(id);
            console.log(authorized_users.indexOf(id));
       }
       
             //console.log(authorized_users.indexOf(id))
        
       function authorization(id){
       // console.log(id)
          id = parseInt(id);

        
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            if(isNaN(id) || id<0 || id==0) { // 
            throw new Error('Invalid User ID');
          } 
         
           
            if(isNaN(id) || id<0 || id==0 || !authorized_users.includes(id)) {
            resolve({
                id : id,
                user_name : 'guest',
                status : 'unauthorized'
            });}
           
            else{

            reject({
                id : id,
                user_name : user_names[authorized_users.indexOf(id)],
                status : 'authorized'
            });       
          }});

          authorization(id).then( function(value) {document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = 'User Id: '+id+'<br>'+'User Name: '+value.user_name+'<br>'+'Authorization: '+value.status; },
                function(err) {document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = 'User Id: '+id+'<br>'+'User Name: '+value.user_name+'<br>'+'Authorization: '+value.status; })
            .catch( error => console.log(error));
        }


       
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you always want it to resolve, don't call reject and don't throw Errors.

Comment: I wanted to help you. I ran your code and you have multiple errors that can be easily fixed by debugging.